# How to get an Affine Transform which has a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

The default OpenCV command "getAffineTransform" gives a 2x3 matrix.
I would like to know how to get a 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=getaffinetransform), notice that a 3x3 affine transformation matrix is of the form

```
r00 r01 tx
r10 r11 ty
  0   0  1
```

So the last row is always `[0 0 1`]. Here, `r` is the rotational part and `t` is the translational part. A usual trick to save space is to represent affine 3x3 matrices as 2x3 matrices by just forgetting the last row, i.e.

```
r00 r01 tx
r10 r11 ty
```

So you just have to append a last row of `[0 0 1]` to it in order to get your 3x3 matrix.